# Golang - Returning null value when return type is string

Tags: json, go, null

I have a go struct something like this

```
type Country struct {
    WhoAllAreComing    []string `json:"attendees"`
    NameOfThePlace     string   `json:"name"`
    EventDate          string   `json:"eventDate"`
}
```

This is the response struct that I need to send back after ingesting the input and manipulating it.

Now if suppose the `EventDate` is empty, I need to pass a **null** in the json response and not an empty string.
How do we convert an empty string in go to a null in json response.

Using `json.Marshall` to marshall my response into Json is just converting it to empty string for EventDate.

Comment: Use a pointe or implement json.Unmarshaler. SO is full of questions about JSON and Go.

Comment: so if i understand what you are saying, something like this      <br/>                                 `{ WhoAllAreComing []string json:"attendees" NameOfThePlace string json:"name" EventDate *string json:"eventDate" }`   <br/>

Comment: Sorry i cant seem to format it right. ...  However, how can I verify that its actually null and not empty string after making eventTime as *string instead of string

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to return a null instead of an empty string.

```
type Country struct {
    WhoAllAreComing    []string `json:"attendees"`
    NameOfThePlace     string   `json:"name"`
    EventDate          *string   `json:"eventDate"`
}
```